# Loop Convert text to number while avoiding cells with leading zero

Tags: excel, vba

SAP exports make all numbers into text I need to keep cells with leading zero as text while converting the rest if numeric text to number.

```
Sub ConvertUsingLoop()
For Each r In Sheets("Loop&CSng").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
If IsNumeric(r) Then
r.Value = CSng(r.Value)
r.NumberFormat = "General"
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'm trying incorporate `Left(Str, 1) = "0"` to exclude cells with leading zero.
Thank you for your input.

Comment: Are they all a standard number of digits?  If so, convert them all to numbers and use a custom number format to show the leading 0's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code that I reached:

```
Sub Text2Number()
    On Error GoTo EH

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

Set Rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Rng.Cells(1, 1).Select

For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
        If Rng.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
            Union(Selection, Rng.Cells(i, j)).Select
        End If
    Next j
Next i
For Each c In Rng.Cells
    If IsNumeric(c.Value) And Left$(c.Value, 1) <> "0" Then
        c.NumberFormat = "General"
     c.Value = c.Value
    End If
Next
CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
EH:
    ' Do error handling
    Resume CleanUp
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps just add your `Left$` check to the `If`:

```
If IsNumeric(r.Value)  And Left$(r.Value, 1) <> "0" Then
```

Comment: I made it work this way but I still need to make it work on active sheet and with selection Thank you `Sub RoundToZero2()
 For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Cells
 If IsNumeric(c.Value) And Left$(c.Value, 1) <> "0" Then
 c.NumberFormat = "General"
 c.Value = c.Value
 End If
 Next
End Sub`